# build failed with an exception in flutter - 'dart: html'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, import, dependencies, yaml

My app worked fine, but now I have this issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/username/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991

it doesn't find dart html????
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/deejaymk/Flutter/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_form_builder: ^5.0.0
  google_fonts: ^1.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post the output of `flutter build apk --v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your file for a `import:dart.html` delete it if you find it

Comment: Thank you! I have deleted it, but now I have that issue:

Comment: what issue are u facing ?

Comment: Thank you! it helped! now it works fine! Actually I am trying to get user UID from firebase...and it seems that I have some difficulties with it. Maybe I did a mistake in my code...now it seems to work fine and reg. user uid I will check on stackoverflow.

Comment: mark this as answer and post another message to the user uid ill try to answer